# Python3 subprocess and if elif else condition

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, popen

Below the running script which is producing the user's ID information, However while searching through a file where i have multiple users it also print is user names which are not existing of fails to resolve in Linux `id` command such as:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

CRED = '\033[91m'
CGRN = '\033[92m'
CEND = '\033[0m'

with open("kkdiff", "r") as lid:
    for line in lid:
        line = line.strip()
        proc = Popen(['id', line], stdout=PIPE,)
        myID = proc.communicate()[0].decode('utf-8')
        if re.search(r'\bkoint\b', myID):
            print(line, CGRN + "Success: " + CEND + "User exists in the Group")
        else:
            print(line, CRED + "Failed: " + CEND + "User does not exists in the Group")
```

**Situation**

```
id <username> results <no such user>
#id: user1: No such user    <-- This is ideal in Linux systems
```

So, while using `id` command with python subprocess module it returns the same `#id: user1: No such user` on the Terminal. However it also returns the `user1 Failed: User does not exists in the Group` as this is what i have asked in else statement.

can we get it through `if, elif, else`  like:

if word found then `"Sucess : user is in group"`, elif `no such user` then `"User is not the AD"` else `"Failed: user is not in group"`

**Script output:**

```
id: user1: No such user
user1 Failed: User does not exists in the Group
user30 Success: User exists in the Group 
user81 Success: User exists in the Group
```

**Desired output:**

```
user1: No such user
user30 Success: User exists in the Group 
user81 Success: User exists in the Group
```

Answer (score 1):

You've assumed that `id` write message to stdout. But, in fact, it write it into stderr.

```
$ id foo >/dev/null
id: ‘foo’: no such user
$ id foo 2>/dev/null
(empty output)
```

To get access to `stderr` of the Popen'ed process, use `proc.communicate()[1]`.

Comment: thnx for the great input but how i could adjust my code.

Comment: adding `stderr=PIPE`  will not on the terminal but it will remain in else condition :-)